# SWT Combo/List only allows to add item value, but no key

Tags: java, swt

Is there a way to store both key and value in an item in a SWT Combo/List? If not, are there SWT components that look like a Combo and/or List that do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at JFace, especially the viewers. The [ComboViewer](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/ntopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ComboViewer.html) should be the right tool for the job.

Basically, the viewers are there for mapping between your domain objects and SWT components. There is even data binding functionality available which saves you a lot of boiler-plate code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.  Use the `setData( String key, Object value )` method.

Answer (score 0):

JFace Structured Viewers are the answer. Learn more about them [here](http://www.ralfebert.de/rcpbuch/jface/). They have a special combo implementation.